# jQuery hover not working after hover on autosuggestion

Tags: jquery, css

I had a button and using jQuery hover to display the form. The hover works perfectly, but when I want to fill the form, the text box will display the auto suggestion. When I hover on the auto suggestion, the form fade out. What possible technique can I use to solve this?

[image: Screen Shot]

```
<div class="dropdown-menu" style="width:600px; height: 350px;padding:40px 40px;">
                                        <h2>Sign In</h2>
                                        <p class="dropdown-text-p" style="font-size:12px;margin-top:20px;">Don't have an account? Create your account. It's take less then a minutes</p>
                                        <form class="form" id="formLogin">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <input type="text" autocomplete="false" class="form-control sign-in-dropdown-input" id="name" placeholder="User Name">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <input type="password" class="form-control sign-in-dropdown-input" id="password" placeholder="Password">
                                            </div>
                                            <div style="margin-top:30px;">
                                                <div class="input-field s4">
                                                    <input type="submit" value="Sign In" class="waves-effect waves-light log-in-btn"> </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </form>
                                    </div>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".sign-in-dropdown").hover(function(){
        $(".dropdown-menu").fadeIn();
        }, function(){
        $(".dropdown-menu").css("display", "none");
    });

        $(".dropdown-menu").hover(function(){
             $(".dropdown-menu").css("display", "block");
             }, function(){
             $(".dropdown-menu").fadeOut();
     });

     $(".dropdown-menu").click(function(){
            $(".dropdown-menu").css("display", "block");
    });

    $( ".sign-in-dropdown-input" ).focus(function() {
      $(".dropdown-menu").css("display", "block");
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: any chance that you can share your precious code with us?

Comment: It work but when I release hover the form, the form not fade out

Comment: @Firdaus You want to only fade out when you hover on the auto suggest?

Comment: @DragonBorn, No , what i mean is when I hover on sign in button the form will fadeIn, after that when i fill in the form (not press submit button) and i release the mouse from the form. The form not fade out.

Comment: @Firdaus Check now

Answer (score 0):

> No , what i mean is when I hover on sign in button the form will fadeIn, after that when i fill in the form (not press submit button) and i release the mouse from the form. The form not fade out.

I have edited your code. Check the snippet. It works exactly as you said in the quoted text above.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".sign-in-dropdown").hover(function(){
        $(".dropdown-menu").fadeIn();
        }, function(){
        $(".dropdown-menu").css("display", "none");
    });

       $(".dropdown-menu").hover(function(){
             $(".dropdown-menu").css("display", "block");
             });
             

     $(".dropdown-menu").click(function(){
            $(".dropdown-menu").css("display", "block");
    });

    $( ".sign-in-dropdown-input" ).focus(function() {
      $(".dropdown-menu").css("display", "block");
    });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="dropdown">
<button class="btn btn-danger sign-in-dropdown">SIGN IN</button>

<div class="dropdown-menu" style="width:600px; height: 350px;padding:40px 40px;">
     <h2>Sign In</h2>
     <p class="dropdown-text-p" style="font-size:12px;margin-top:20px;">Don't have an account? Create your account. It's take less then a minutes</p>
     <form class="form" id="formLogin">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" autocomplete="false" class="form-control sign-in-dropdown-input" id="name" placeholder="User Name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" class="form-control sign-in-dropdown-input" id="password" placeholder="Password">
        </div>

        <div style="margin-top:30px;">
            <div class="input-field s4">
                <input id="sign-in-btn" type="submit" value="Sign In" class="waves-effect waves-light log-in-btn"> 
            </div>
        </div>
     </form>
</div>
</div>
```